# Running Docker with Apache WSGI side by side with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, docker

I need to run Docker side by side with Apache on one server.
Apache currently has a few virtual hosts and Docker has Apache with a specific Python version together with WSGI on it.

I need to set them up together without changing a lot of configuration of virtual hosts which are already there. Basically I need to forward port 80 from container as Apache virtual host or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the Apache on the host proxy requests for a certain virtual host, through to another Apache instance running inside of  a Docker container?

Comment: yes if this is possible, if not what will be the closest alternative? I don't want to move all those other sites around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName host.example.com
ProxyPass / http://docker.example.com:1234
ProxyPassReverse / http://docker.example.com:1234
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace `host.example.com` with the actual host name for the virtual host.

Replace `docker.example.com` with the actual host name or IP for the Docker host. If same host, you can use `localhost`.

Replace `1234` with the port which was exported by Docker for the container running your WSGI application.

Your WSGI application will have to pay attention to `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Host` headers set by front end Apache when proxying. If your WSGI application can't do that, then might be a good idea to use mod_wsgi instead as it has inbuilt support for dealing with that.

The Docker image for mod_wsgi can be found at:

- https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/grahamdumpleton/mod-wsgi-docker/

The additional options you would need to supply to mod_wsgi-express are:

```
--trust-proxy-header X-Forwarded-For
--trust-proxy-header X-Forwarded-Host
```

If the fix ups aren't done so that the original virtual host name and port are updated in the WSGI environ or by the WSGI application in some other way, the WSGI application when constructing URLs for use in pages and response headers will not generate the correct values.

If you are after more than that, you are going to have to explain it a bit better.

If you want to use the mod_wsgi Docker image, see the Docker Hub page and the blog posts linked from it. Then jump on the mod_wsgi mailing list if need more help.

---

For more information about the general issues around proxying Apache to backend Python web sites which use mod_wsgi, see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html